# Does javascript autorefresh on webpage create extra load on server?

Tags: php, server

I have implemented auto refresh function on a webpage which refresh page after 2 second. Initially I wanted to do this using shall script which will hit that url in every 2 second. but server administrator advised me that it is not good to hit a page in every 2 second because it create extra load to server. Now I want to know if autorefresh also create the extra load to server same as shall script.
Thanks

Comment: it depends, if all the client side is cached and theres no other calls to the server then it wont affect it. but i still don't reccomend doing so. why do you need to refresh the entire page every 2seconds?

Comment: What you are asking for is pretty much one of the go-to use cases for AJAX - don't refresh the entire page - just fetch the updated parts with asynchronous requests and update the DOM. Definitely more light-weight than a full page refresh. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/558715/11447682

Comment: Thanks @tom-slabbaert. I am developing a application in which user can post a job and other can bid on the job. Those user have 50 seconds to bid for the job and it is awarded on some points basis. I need to implement this to update the status after Job award and every task can assign to user with in time. I know client side scripting is not good for this purpose but need to implement temporarily until find the alternate server side solution for this.